# partial derivative of a facet normal wrt to one of its vertex

Tags: calculus, multivariable-calculus, derivatives, computer-science, partial-derivative

I am struggling to understand the derivation of an equation in a paper ([A Bayesian Method for Probable Surface Reconstruction and Decimation](http://robots.stanford.edu/papers/diebel.surface.pdf), specifically Eqn. 16).

Basically they define three vertices of a facet: $x_k, x_{k'},x_{k''}$ 
The normalized facet normal is defined as: $n_i = \dfrac{(x_{k'}-x_k) \times (x_{k''}-x_k)}{|(x_{k'}-x_k) \times (x_{k''}-x_k)|}$

So far so good. The problem is then that they need to compute $\frac{\partial n_i}{\partial x_k}$. Firstly ${n_i}$ and ${x_k}$ are both vectors, hence I'd expect that this partial derivative notation means in effect the Jacobian of ${n_i}$ wrt. ${x_k}$? In that case that is a 3x3 matrix. However the formula below (see Eqn 16) implies that the result is a 3x1 vector?? (confused!)

$\frac{\partial n_i}{\partial x_k} = \frac{I - n_in_i^T}{|(x_{k'} - x_k) \times (x_{k''} - x_k)|} (x_{k''} - x_{k'}) \times x_k$

I was hoping someone could shed some light on the dimensionallity confusion and also how that formula was derived, or if incorrect what is the correct forumation for $\frac{\partial n_i}{\partial x_k}$?  Thanks for the help!

Comment: Formula (16) is not the only weird one: on the second line of formula (14) the authors multiply a $(3,1)$-type matrix (a vector) by a $(3,3)$-type matrix...

Comment: @AlexM. that one (eqn 14) is probably just missing the transpose on the vector...

Comment: Eqn 14 looks like the chain rule but if you think it's incorrect let me know haha

Comment: Yes, it is supposed to be the chain rule, but it doesn't look like it. Maybe you are right and they are just missing a transpose.